# How to run task scheduler everyday at the same time in R?

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, r-taskscheduler

How can I set a script to run everyday automatically at 11:00pm?

I found the package "taskscheduleR", but I don't know how to run my script with it.

**taskschedulerR exemple:**

```
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")

## run script once within 62 seconds taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript", rscript = myscript, schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M"))
```

**My script**

```
dayfile <- read.csv("A:/file_170611.txt", sep = " ", header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)
write.table(dayfile, file="A:/dayfiles/dayfile.txt", sep = " ")
```

Comment: Are you using windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [README of taskscheduleR](https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR) looks quite on the point:

```
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- "A:/script.R" # path to script
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myscriptdaily", rscript = myscript, 
    schedule = "DAILY", starttime = "09:10", 
    startdate = format(Sys.Date()+1, "%d/%m/%Y")
)
```

and you are done.

Comment: Why the code format is "format(Sys.Date()+1" ? I didn't understand this part of the code.

Comment: Sys.Date() is today, Sys.Date()+1 is tomorrow. So the script is first executed tomorrow morning 9:10. `format` converts a Date object to a character.